# F# execute XSL Transform from XML String and returns string

Tags: xslt, f#, xslcompiledtransform

looking at the XSLCompiledTransform Class in .NET at trying to find a concise way to use it in F#. I am unfamiliar with string readers/writers but am looking at that as primary method to accomplish this. Or do I want XML readers?

I have a function that will take two arguments - an XML string and an XSLT stylesheet. I want to return a string of XML.

```
let applyXSLTransform xml xslFile =        
        let xslt = XslCompiledTransform()
        xslt.Load(xslFile)
        xslt.Transform(xml, outputToString); //This bit
```

It's nice and easy to do with files but seems a bit more involved to read and write to strings. I have seen a few C# samples and not having immediate success in getting them to work so still doing research onto readers and writers!

Cheers

Comment: A C# way is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16395226/252228, I am not good at F#, perhaps a transpiler like https://github.com/jindraivanek/cs2fs can do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easier way to use the API than using the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` interfaces. This is unfortunately quite tedious, but the following should do the trick:

```
open System.IO
open System.Text
open System.Xml
open System.Xml.Xsl

let applyXSLTransform xml (xslFile:string) =        
  let xslt = XslCompiledTransform()
  let sbuilder = StringBuilder()
  use swriter = new StringWriter(sbuilder)
  use sreader = new StringReader(xml)
  use xreader = new XmlTextReader(sreader)
  use xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(swriter)
  xslt.Load(xslFile)
  xslt.Transform(xreader, xwriter)
  sbuilder.ToString()
```

The code constructs `StringBuilder`, which is an in-memory object for constructing strings. It wraps this around `StringWriter` and `XmlTextWriter` to be passed to the `Transform` method. At the end, you read the contents of the `StringBuilder` using the `ToString` method. Similar thing happens to create `XmlTextReader` for data from `StringReader`, which contains your input XML.

Comment: This works well and marked as accepted since it handles the file load as well, though yours and Martin's are both functionally identical and I like both solutions. Not the most tedious thing I've encountered in my F# learnings by any means!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I could come up with, trying to use the recommended `XmlReader.Create` factory methods instead of the .NET 1 legacy XmlTextReader:

```
open System
open System.Xml.Xsl
open System.Xml
open System.IO

let transform xml xslt =
    let processor = XslCompiledTransform()

    use xsltreader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslt))

    processor.Load(xsltreader)

    use xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml))
    
    use resultwriter = new StringWriter()

    processor.Transform(xmlreader, null, resultwriter)

    resultwriter.ToString()
```

But I have no deep knowledge of F#, just tried to convert my C# coding way to F#.

Comment: As far as I can tell this works fine, "using" was a C# construct I was unfamiliar with so wasn't sure how to translate it. Thanks!